# ASP.NET 4 webforms clientid suffixed with `_0`

Tags: webforms, asp.net-4.0, clientid

Last year we moved all our new functionality to ASP.NET MVC.

However we still have a load of legacy WebForms pages with lots of JavaScript code, and we're not going to get the chance to upgrade them any time soon.

More recently we also moved to ASP.NET 4, and that seems to have broken a load of the JavaScript code on these legacy pages.

Where before the client id would be:

```
ctl001_masterControlName_panelControlName_controlWeWant
```

Now they have become:

```
ctl001_masterControlName_panelControlName_controlWeWant_0
```

Where does that `_0` suffix come from? There's only one `controlWeWant` in `panelControlName`, so the suffix adds no value.

I know hardcoded client ids are a bad idea with WebForms; one of the reasons we moved to ASP.NET MVC was the awful HTML produced by WebForms. However for this legacy code we're stuck with it, and I'd rather not go changing it (until the day comes when we have some free time to do it properly).

Why is ASP.NET 4 adding the `_0` suffix at all?

Can I turn it off?

Is there another way to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out *[What is New in ASP.NET 4.0 - ClientID Generation for a Cleaner MarkUp](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=492&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)*. It explains some new functionality in ASP.NET 4.0 when it comes to id generation.

Comment: That's great - it looks like future WebForms programmers will be able to make it produce slightly less awful HTML (those that haven't already run for the MVC hills). Unfortunately it doesn't answer my question: why has it added `_0` to the client id and how can I remove it without rewriting everything?

Comment: Thanks, but that describes a similar problem with a different cause - they were duplicating ids so the suffix was being automatically generated (on Asp.Net 2 too by the looks of it). I have a page that worked in Asp.Net 2, but in 4 the same code (recompiled) now has `_0` suffixed to the client ids and I want it to behave like it used to.

Comment: Well, it's hard to say without a real world sample, but.. It's an effect of what the last link was about. Here's one more link that describes it: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031710-1.aspx

Comment: Ah, that lead to something that appears to be the cause - the control is in a table, so stupid WebForms assumes that it will repeat the row content and adds the `_0` just in case. Unfortunately the question remains - how do I turn this breaking change off?

Comment: Try this link: http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx If you set the id generation mode to Legacy then you should get the old behaviour